# ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError index item_core,item_delta: query error: no field 'deleted_at' found in schema

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx, acts-as-paranoid

I have an `Item` model:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
...
define_index do
  ...
  has deleted_at
  indexes deleted_at
end
...
```

Then I stop the server, run `rake ts:rebuild && rake ts:reindex && rake ts:restart`, restart the server. And I still get the error.

The query that triggers the error is this:

```
Item.search({conditions:  {deleted_at: nil}})
```

What's wrong ?

---

*Note:* I am using [acts_as_paranoid](https://github.com/goncalossilva/acts_as_paranoid). My database is migrated, the table `items` has the column `deleted_at`.

Somewhere in schema.rb:

```
...
create_table "items", :force => true do |t|
  ...
  t.datetime "deleted_at"
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of related issues here:

- You've got an attribute and a field with the same name (deleted_at) - you should alias one to have a different name using the :as option. Otherwise, Sphinx gets confused when reading the generated SQL data.
- You've got a date column as a field, when it almost certainly isn't required - do you want users searching by deleted_at, or is it purely something for you to manage internally? I'm guessing the latter. So, remove the `indexes deleted_at` line.
- You're setting a field condition in your search call when it should really be an attribute filter - which is done using the `:with` option.
- Sphinx has no concept of nil, but should translate NULL values from the database into zeros.

So, with all that in mind, your index definition should rather be:

```
define_index do
  # ...

  has deleted_at
end
```

Run `rake ts:rebuild` to ensure Sphinx is aware of the changes and your index files are updated.

Then your search call is:

```
Item.search with: {deleted_at: 0}
```